# Android custom launcher without declaring all apps in manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, launcher

I'm creating more or less a custom launcher, based on the wonderfully simple code I found [online](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/create-application-launcher-as-a-list/). Basically it lists all applications:

```
final List<ApplicationInfo> applications = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Then when one is clicked, it launches the activity:

```
    final Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationInfo.packageName);
    if(launchIntent != null)
    {
        context.startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
```

This works fine with, for example, Calculator. But for others, such as Contacts, I get an exception:

```
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438): Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.contacts/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.contacts/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at com.globalmentor.android.app.Applications.launch(Applications.java:68)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at com.globalmentor.android.app.Applications.launch(Applications.java:52)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at com.globalmentor.android.app.ApplicationLaunchListActivity.onApplicationClick(ApplicationLaunchListActivity.java:41)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at com.globalmentor.android.app.ApplicationListActivity$1.onItemClick(ApplicationListActivity.java:66)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-25 13:32:43.436: E/ApplicationLaunchListActivity(438):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Several obvious questions present themselves: Do I have to declare the Contacts activity in the activity manifest? But why don't I have to declare Calculator in the activity manifest? And how does the default launcher handle applications that my be dynamically installed at any time---long after the manifest was written?

Comment: Try this sample app instead and see if you have better luck: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot